# CakePHP: Time input with quarter-accuracy

Tags: html, forms, cakephp, time

I'm using

```
$form->input("time")
```

to render select boxes for time input. They have minute-accuracy, which I don't need.

How could I limit the select lists to quarters (XX:00, XX:15, XX:30, XX:45)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
   <?php echo $form->input('time', array('type' => 'time', 'interval' => 15)); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

This URL might help you: http://book.cakephp.org/view/189/Automagic-Form-Elements#options-interval-757

I hope this helps!